# Disabling Node.js download in KotlinJS Gradle plugin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js

The version of Node.js that KotlinJS downloads (as of 1.3.40+) seems not to work in Alpine Linux. The docker image I'm using already has Node baked into it, so there's no reason not to use that one.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to set [download](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/102a3d60e03930ad59b2719e1a5438fff213b1ac/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/targets/js/nodejs/NodeJsRootExtension.kt#L32) to `false` (which should cause KotlinJS to build using the `node` on the PATH).

The relevant section of my build.gradle looks like this:

```
kotlin {
    target {
        useCommonJs()
        browser()
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's pretty similar to @talalUcef's answer:

```
kotlinNodeJs {
    download = false
}
```

1. Using the [KotlinBrowserJs](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/3e251668324f3ac2f0819ca6bef0ce97ca26f39b/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/targets/js/subtargets/KotlinBrowserJs.kt) plugin [applies](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/3e251668324f3ac2f0819ca6bef0ce97ca26f39b/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/targets/js/subtargets/KotlinBrowserJs.kt#L43) the [NodeJsRoot](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/102a3d60e03930ad59b2719e1a5438fff213b1ac/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/targets/js/nodejs/NodeJsRootPlugin.kt) plugin.
2. The [NodeJsRoot](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/targets/js/nodejs/NodeJsRootPlugin.kt#L37) plugin applies itself, which causes the [NodeJsRootExtension](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/targets/js/nodejs/NodeJsRootPlugin.kt#L18) to be included under the name [`kotlinNodeJs`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/targets/js/nodejs/NodeJsRootExtension.kt#L112).
   Thus, I believe, any of the vars [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/targets/js/nodejs/NodeJsRootExtension.kt#L30-L38) can be set inside a `kotlinNodeJs` block.

Answer (score -1):

You can add

```
node {
    download = false
}
```

on your build.gradle file

Comment: Thanks, I think that works for the [moowork](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md) plugin, but unfortunately doesn't affect the KotlinJS plugin.